# Google snippets and "SECURITY WARNING...facebook". How to fix it?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I installed a plugin for facebook autoconnect. It works, 
but I realized I have a problem with google snippets. 
Most of the results shows this: "SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the above URL as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Center for more ..."

I updated to the latest version the plugin and reload the sitemap to google, but nothing has changed. 
What I want is to know if the problem is in the plugin, or from the app I created to run the plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/331983440290482/dashboard/
This happens to me only with google snippets and not trying to register. 
What can I do to fix it?

thanks

Comment: We can't access your app dashboard.

Comment: yes sure, it's private. Anyway there's no error on this app